# How to control looping with Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, loops, django-templates

I am trying to use the Django template to loop over a set of records, but stop one short, and then process the last one differently. So lets say I have 50 records - I would want to loop over 1 to 49 and then stop, and then process the 50th outside the loop. I am trying to create

```
    [[date, var2],[date, var2],..[date, var2]*];
```

I am using:

```
    data.addRows([
      {% for data in mydata %}
         [{{data.date}},{{data.var2}}],
      {% endfor %}
    ]);
```

My aim is to NOT include the comma (indicated by the *) but to keep the required form. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is forloop.last that makes it possible to do this task entirely within the loop.

```
data.addRows([
      {% for data in mydata %}
         {% if forloop.last %}
             [{{data.date}},{{data.var2}}]
         {% else %}
             [{{data.date}},{{data.var2}}],
         {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    ]);
```

There is an alternative, the [last](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#last) filter which returns the last item on a list, but the above method is the more conventional way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks, e4c5, that gave me exactly what I needed.

Comment: glad to have been of help